# Can't see the issue on why my event handler is not firing my function

Tags: javascript

I am creating an input and I want to create a console log 5 seconds after the last key down.  I am trying to handle this through a debounce function but can't see where I am messing it up.  It is not firing the log.

```
<div>
  <input id="test" onkeydown="handleDebounce(logIt, 5000)"/>
</div>


function logIt() {
   console.log('testing');
}

function handleDebounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeoutId; 
  
  return function() {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
       fn();
    }, delay);
 
  }
}
```

It is not logging anything.  I tried tracing the issue but can't tell.

Comment: The obvious problem is in your logit function you are wrapping console.log in console.log and missing the last ). So I would try removing the first reference to console.log

Comment: @imvain2 I am sorry, I transferred this wrong from my editor. I have it correctly there but just translated poorly here.  I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because from `handleDebounce`, you are returning function that will actually create the timer and so on, but that function is never executed, you should either do the logic in `handleDebounce`, or call the function, in html:

```
<input id="test" onkeydown="handleDebounce(logIt, 5000)()"/>
```

Comment: thanks Nikita!  How is this approach different from the solution below where the anonymous function was removed entirely? I am confused as to why the tutorials I saw made use of the anonymous function then if it's not needed

Comment: In this case not really different - as i also suggested that you could do that. What tutorial you referring to? I guess in that tutorial they explained scope principles and closures, which you might have misunderstood and misuse

Comment: thanks.  I watched this guy explain it, who does a fairly good job of explaining concepts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1P3GFa7jVc

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by:

Fixing the broken console.log reference.

Moving the declaring of timeoutID outside of the function.

and removing the returning of the anonymous function that doesn't return anything and isn't actually being called.

```js
function logIt() {
   console.log('testing');
}

var timeoutId; 
function handleDebounce(fn, delay) {
  
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
       fn();
    }, delay);
 
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="test" onkeydown="handleDebounce(logIt, 5000)"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When attaching the inline event handlers, you will also have to invoke the function and not just the function reference.

A cleaner way to write this is to remove the inline event handler and add the handler in the JS

```
<input id="test" onkeydown="handleDebounce(logIt, 5000)()"/>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('keydown', handleDebounce(logIt, 2000))


function logIt() {
   console.log('testing');
}

function handleDebounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeoutId; 
  
  return function() {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
       fn();
    }, delay);
 
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="test" />
</div>
```